# Google play services doesn't get installed

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, youtube, google-play-services

I just wanted to upload a video on YouTube but after updating the app to the latest version , it says that it needs Google Play Services to run. I tapped different places of the screen because it sometimes works with other apps, but this case is not the same. I tried hitting the back button and it just quit. I installed that Google app several times but it doesn't get installed. What should I do?

Comment: You can download the Google Play Services APK file from APK Mirror, just read the instructions on how to find the correct version for your device:  http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from here, 
you need to search for your android version.
http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/
you need to download for your android version>4.1/4.4/5.1/6.0
or try to reinstall YouTube

I have the same problem.

I just download play services and problem was fixed.

EDIT:they support android 2.3+ im using old android phone now,and I can confirm that they support ,also confirm that it's  working for 4.0.